# When evaluating this integral Mathematica returns two different answers

Tags: functions, calculus-and-analysis

When evaluating this integral in *Mathematica* 10.3 Student Edition:

```
L = {11458.4, 8955.01, 6382.1, 3906.58, 1540.8, 447.394, 71.239, 36.588, 22.825, 16.088};
cC = 1/.19733;
P = Table[1 - Sin[m2 *L[[j]] /(4 xe)*cC]^2, {j, 1, 10}]
Y = 4/3;

Rexp1 = Table[(Integrate[xe^(-Y)*P[[j]], {xe, 0.1, 0.4}])/(Integrate[
 xe^(-Y), {xe, 0.1, 0.4}]), {j, 1, 10}]
```

I get a first term which looks like:

```
0.418117*(1.19584 + E^((0. + 290336.*I)*m2)*(-1.81239/10^29 + (0. + (7.89303*I)/10^24)*m2 - 
     ((0. + (3.52461*I)/10^38)*m2^3)/((0. - 1.*I)*m2)^2.) - 
   (0.00813404*Gamma[0.333333, (0. - 290336.*I)*m2])/((0. - 1.*I)*m2)^0.333333)
```

When evaluating with an older version of *Mathematica* I get:

```
0.418117*(2.39168 + (1/m2)*(-1.19584*m2 + (0. + 0.0000136687*I)*((0. - 14516.8*I)*m2)^(2/3)*
      (1.*Gamma[0.333333, (0. - 72584.*I)*m2] - 1.*Gamma[0.333333, (0. - 290336.*I)*m2]) - 
     (0. + 0.0000136687*I)*((0. + 14516.8*I)*m2)^(2/3)*
      (1.*Gamma[0.333333, (0. + 72584.*I)*m2] - 1.*Gamma[0.333333, (0. + 290336.*I)*m2])))
```

Why is this? The result given by the older version of *Mathematica* works in the rest of the program and the newer one breaks it. How can I get my old result back?

Comment: Are you sure those results aren't actually the same? Have you tried plugging in values for `m2`?

Comment: The old version of *Mathematica* is version 9?

Comment: I can't plug in values of m2 as m2 is found by minimising a graph further into the notebook.
Yes the old version I used was Mathematica version 9.

Comment: http://www.filedropper.com/subgevless400mulike

http://www.filedropper.com/showdownload.php/subgevless400mulike-copy
Attached are the two files, one has been evaluated in the new version, the other not. For reference.

Comment: You are getting two different results, because the numerical errors produced by the two versions of *Mathematic* are different.

Comment: Yes but how can I fix them back to the way they were? Or fix my program to work with the new errors? I tried the chop function to see if that would help but it didn't.